# Transform table to get desired data

Tags: mysql, transform

Sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `pract` (
  `name` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ;

insert into pract (`name`,`tag`,`value`) values 
                  ('n1','tag1',10),
                  ('n1','tag2',14),
                  ('n1','tag3',13),
                  ('n2','tag1',12),
                  ('n2','tag2',14),
                  ('n2','tag3',17);
```

Show data in table `pract`:

```
select * from pract;
+------+------+-------+
| name | tag  | value |
+------+------+-------+
| n1   | tag1 |    10 |
| n1   | tag2 |    14 |
| n1   | tag3 |    13 |
| n2   | tag1 |    12 |
| n2   | tag2 |    14 |
| n2   | tag3 |    17 |
+------+------+-------+
```

Create a table `result` :

```
CREATE TABLE `result` (
  `name` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag1` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag2` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tag3` decimal(2,0) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ;
```

How can get the following table from `pract` after creating table `result`?

```
+------+------+------+------+
| name | tag1 | tag2 | tag3 |
+------+------+------+------+
| n1   |   10 |   14 |   13 |
| n2   |   12 |   14 |   17 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Do as `sticky bit` say:

```
INSERT INTO result
            (name,
             tag1,
             tag2,
             tag3)
SELECT name,
       max(CASE
             WHEN tag = 'tag1' THEN
               value
           END) tag1,
       max(CASE
             WHEN tag = 'tag2' THEN
               value
           END) tag1,
       max(CASE
             WHEN tag = 'tag3' THEN
               value
           END) tag3
       FROM pract;
```

Show the data in `result`:

```
select * from result;
+------+------+------+------+
| name | tag1 | tag2 | tag3 |
+------+------+------+------+
| n1   |   12 |   14 |   17 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Have a try with :

```
SELECT name,
       CASE
             WHEN tag = 'tag1' THEN
               value
           END tag1,
       CASE
             WHEN tag = 'tag2' THEN
               value
           END tag1,
       CASE
             WHEN tag = 'tag3' THEN
               value
           END tag3
       FROM pract;
```

What i get is as below:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| name | tag1 | tag1 | tag3 |
+------+------+------+------+
| n1   |   10 | NULL | NULL |
| n1   | NULL |   14 | NULL |
| n1   | NULL | NULL |   13 |
| n2   |   12 | NULL | NULL |
| n2   | NULL |   14 | NULL |
| n2   | NULL | NULL |   17 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

It is very near to my expection:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| name | tag1 | tag2 | tag3 |
+------+------+------+------+
| n1   |   10 |   14 |   13 |
| n2   |   12 |   14 |   17 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data, and, in my view, issues of presentation are best resolved in a presentation layer.

Comment: And note that if (name,tag) is primary, then define it as such

Answer (score -1):

You can use conditional aggregation.

```
INSERT INTO result
            (name,
             tag1,
             ...
             tag3)
SELECT name,
       max(CASE
             WHEN tag = 'tag1' THEN
               value
           END) tag1,
       ...
       max(CASE
             WHEN tag = 'tag3' THEN
               value
           END) tag3,
       FROM pract;
```